# How can I redirect with extra information in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

I'd like to perform a redirect, but I also wish to send additional information along with it.

I've tried to change the value of `window.location.href` but that doesn't seem to pass along the extra information.

I also get how I can do

```
    $.get(
        new_url,
        {data : "mydata"},
        function(data) {
           alert('page content: ' + data);
        }
    );
```

and that will display the html content of the new page, but that doesn't help with actually getting there.
How can I achieve this?

Edit:  I feel as if I must be phrasing this terribly because I'm pretty sure this is an easy/common task.  This shouldn't be something that would require cookies - it should basically be like a post request (I think).

Comment: Can you not use `localStorage`?

Comment: Wait, what have you tried? Doesn't it work `//test.com?extraparam=what`? Now i'm just wondering what you mean by `additional information`??? Instead explain your expected behaviour

Comment: You can generate form in jQuery and submit it (`POST`/`GET`)

Comment: @A.Wolff, by additional information, I mean the dictionary you might pass along with a python request object.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: The goal is to redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few different options for this:

- **URI Variables** - You can append extra data to the URL by appending a question mark (?) followed by a set of key-value separated by an ampersand (=) with each variable being separated by an ampersand (&). For instance, http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+url+variables&ie=UTF-8 gives you a link to a Google search for "javascript url variables" using UTF-8 encoding. Your PHP code or JavaScript would need to handle passing along and processing these variables. If using JavaScript a nice library for processing URLs is [URI.js](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) or using PHP you can use the [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) functions. You can use this with `window.location.href`; for instance: `window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+url+variables&ie=UTF-8"` (replace the Google URL with the one you created or set in a variable).
- **[Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage)** - You can use the localStorage or sessionStorage properties to store and retrieve information using JavaScript (information is stored in the user's browser - supported by IE 8 and newer and all other major browsers). Note that this is JavaScript only unless you grab the data with JavaScript and pass it to your PHP server through URL variables, form, AJAX request, etc.
- **Cookie** - You can store additional information inside a cookie - however this is more difficult since you have to setup your variables as a [parsable string](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) (possibly JSON) and remember to encode/decode the string when setting/getting the cookie. I don't recommend this method.
- **[IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)** - This is a more advanced client-side/browser storage mechanism and currently only supported in IE 10 and newer (and nearly all other browsers). There are also still changes being made to the standard which means newer versions of browsers could break current implementations or be buggy. If all you need is simple key-value storage (not an SQL-like database) then you should stick with one of the above options.

Comment: URI Variables were what did it for me. :)

Comment: @Everyone_Else - Glad you could figure it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window open method to redirect your user,and remember to use "_self"

```
window.open('url','_self');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that doesn't allow me to pass on any additional info.

Comment: I don't understand what problem you are facing,can you tell me more?

Answer (score 0):

Preferably you'd store the data in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and fall back to a cookie (I really like [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)).

Here are the two helper functions you need to store and retrieve data:

```
function setMultiPageData(itemName, data) {
    var dataStr = JSON.stringify(data);

    var hasLocalStorage = typeof localStorage !== 'undefined';
    if (hasLocalStorage) {
        localStorage.setItem(itemName, dataStr);
    }
    else {
        Cookies.set(itemName, dataStr, { path: '/' }); // path set to root to make cookie available on any page
    }
}

function getMultiPageData(itemName) {
    var data = null;

    var hasLocalStorage = typeof localStorage !== 'undefined';
    if (hasLocalStorage) {
        data = localStorage.getItem(itemName);
    }

    if (!hasLocalStorage || data === null) {
        data = Cookies.get(itemName);
    }

    var parsedObject = null;
    try {
        parsedObject = JSON.parse(data);
    }
    catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex); // remove in production
    }

    return parsedObject;
}
```

usage:

```
var data = { first: 'this is the first thing', second: 'this is the second thing' };
setMultiPageData('stackoverflow-test', data);

// go to a new page
var retrievedData = getMultiPageData('stackoverflow-test');
if (retrievedData === null) {
    console.log('something went wrong')
}
else {
    console.log(retrievedData); // { first: 'this is the first thing', second: 'this is the second thing' }
}
```